# Qt Auto Connect New Object's Signal to Existing Slot

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qt-signals

I have a simple object library that will be used for storing additional data about variables. As I create each object (to be used as variable), I would like to maintain a QList of these objects. Is there a way to automatically connect all of the newly created object's signals to one slot. The slot belongs to an object within my application.

**Object Header** *ezbool.h*

```
class EZBool : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit EZBool(QObject *parent = 0);
    EZBool(QString boolName, bool initialValue, IOTYPE type);   
    //Removed Member Functions      
signals:
    void localEZBool_Created(EZBool *me);
private:
    QString name;
    bool value;
    IOTYPE ioType;
};
```

**Object Constructor** *ezbool.cpp*

```
EZBool::EZBool(QString boolName, bool initialValue, IOTYPE type)
{
    name = boolName;
    value = initialValue;
    ioType = type;
    emit localEZBool_Created(this);
}
```

**Slot Implementation** *fbtest.cpp*

```
void TestFB::on_localEZBool_Created(EZBool *newVar)
{
    qDebug() << "Auto Connect worked??";
    //Handle new variable by adding to QList
}
```

Objects are created in the following manner within *fbtest.cpp*:

```
void TestFB::initialize()
{
    mpOnCmd     = new EZBool("MpOnCmd", false, IO_INPUT);
    zeroSpeed   = new EZBool("ZeroSpeed", false, IO_INPUT);

}
```

I have tried matching Qt's auto connect feature, but no luck. The auto connect ability was referenced from the following:

[Automatic Connections](http://qtway.blogspot.no/2010/08/automatic-connections-using-qt-signals.html)

[Qt Project Forums](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/4904)

I do not want to manually connect every signal after instantiating each new object. In the following manner:

```
connect(ezBool, SIGNAL(localEZBool_Created(EZBool*)),
        this, SLOT(on_localEZBool_Created(EZBool*)));
```

Does anyone have any recommendations or suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: I actually cannot get the problem. If you need to store new objects in the list, why don't you simply add them to the list soon after creation and want to use signal/slots for it?

Comment: I would prefer if this was occurring behind the scenes, as in it is handled automatically. I certainly understand your suggestion. This application is being designed to create a "base template". The more simple for the user to modify, the better - in this instance having to make an explicit call to add the new object to the list is not more simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override childEvent in TestFB and then react to it for the ChildAdded

```
void TestFB::childEvent(QChildEvent * event)
{
    if(event.added())
    {
        EZBool child = qobject_cast<EZBool*>(event.child());
        if(child)
        {
            qDebug() << "Auto Connect worked??";
            //Handle new variable by adding to QList
        }
    }
}
```

this needs the parent of EZBool to be set to the `TestFB` (preferably in the constructor)

```
mpOnCmd     = new EZBool("MpOnCmd", false, IO_INPUT, this);
zeroSpeed   = new EZBool("ZeroSpeed", false, IO_INPUT, this);
```

and add a `QObject *parent=0` parameter to the custom constructor and pass it to the super class

```
EZBool::EZBool(QString boolName, bool initialValue, IOTYPE type, QObject p)
: QObject(p)
{
    name = boolName;
    value = initialValue;
    ioType = type;
}
```

Comment: Is it safe to emit a signal in constructor like `emit localEZBool_Created(this);` when `this` is not actually created yet?

Comment: probably not, besides nothing would have been connected yet

Comment: @ratchetfreak Thank you very much for your option. Is this the only known way to implement my solution? [Qt Child Created Doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#childEvent) explains that your option would certainly satisfy my need. While this is an alternative solution, I am still curious to know if there  is a way to connect the all signals of a specific object type (regardless of the created instance) to a specified slot. Example: Any instance of EZBool will always connect to TestFB Slot X when EZBool Signal Y is emitted. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

To solve objects list auto-population I wouldn't use signal/slot mechanism at all. It actually seems to be an overkill and unnecessary dependency from QObject. Instead, I would propose the following solution that, IMO, much simpler.

Define the list that will store newly created objects. You can read it whenever you want:

```
static QList<EZBool *> Objects;
```

Class `EZBool` will automatically populate the list with newly created objects:

```
class EZBool
{
public:    
    EZBool(QString boolName, bool initialValue, IOTYPE type)
        :
            name(boolName),
            value(initialValue),
            ioType(type)
    {
        Objects.push_back(this);
    }
private:
    QString name;
    bool value;
    IOTYPE ioType;
};
```

This class is responsible for new EZBool objects creation.

```
class TestFB
{
public:
    void initialize()
    {
        new EZBool("MpOnCmd", false, IO_INPUT);
        new EZBool("ZeroSpeed", false, IO_INPUT);
    } 
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I agree that would work in a normal structure. Maybe I should have included more information on the environment. TestFB is the class within my application, EZBool is a class within an "EZIO" Static Library that I have created. EZBool will not know what the *Objects* QList is because it would not be a member of the EZIO library.

Comment: I was originally hoping that I could have the EZIO library's member EZBool emit a *ObjectCreated* Signal whenever a new EZBool was instantiated. My hope was to have a Slot *NewBoolCreated* within the application that would be connected to the *ObjectCreated* Signal emitted from the EZBool object. Now, I believe my idea may not work for other reasons that yourself and @ratchetfreak have mentioned.